# Writing to file in Qt

Tags: qt, file, path

I have a problem with writing to file, the problem is :
If I write the directory ":/Files/Scores.txt" it won't write anything but it reads from same directory.
But if I used this directory "D:/TicTacToe/TicTacToe/Scores.txt" it writes and reads but i will give the game to my instructor and the path won't be same and the file won't open, any ideas ?!

My write code:

```
void Write ( QString file)
{
QFile sfile(file);
if(!sfile.open(QFile::ReadOnly |QFile::Text))
{
    return;
}
QTextStream in(&sfile);
QString lscores =sfile.readAll() ;
sfile.close();
if(!sfile.open(QFile::WriteOnly |QFile::Text))
{
    return;
}
lscores="     "+Xscore+"\t"+"        "+Oscore+"\n"+lscores;
QTextStream out(&sfile);
out <<lscores;
sfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a relative path instead of an absolute?

Comment: File paths that start with `:/` are reserved for Qt's resource system. These files are part of the binary itself and as such are read-only. You can read more about the resource system [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).

Comment: @AeroBuffalo Can You explain more for me ? What's the deffirence ?

Comment: @MrEricSir So what i can do to make it write with out the full path ?!

Comment: A full, or absolute, path would be something like your TicTacToe path. Then say you are already in the first TicTacToe folder and wanted to reference Score.txt, you could just write `TicTacToe/Sxores.txt`. That is a relative path, and it is relative to your current directory. The following site has a pretty good explanation and examples: http://www.linuxnix.com/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix/

Comment: @MrEricSir now i understand thx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource files (the ones you put in .qrc file) are read only, as MrEricSir mentioned. If you want to have some configuration/score file with your app you can for example use QApplication::applicationDirPath()

```
QString settingsFile = QApplication::applicationDirPath() % QLatin1Literal("/scores.txt");
```

This way you will have always absolute path to the file inside your app directory.

You can also use `QDesktopServices::storageLocation` with `QDesktopServices::DataLocation` parameter to obtain data location for your application.